# Replicate Chromecast bootstrap behavior on Android TV Stick

Tags: remote-control, android-tv, chromecast

Chromecast and a few other devices have the following behavior.

Upon either first start or (I want to do) when known wifi APs are not present, they host a Hotspot which can be connected to from your phone to configure it, possibly to setup the AP that it should connect to.

I would like to replicate this on an android stick I have.

Usecase: I take the android stick on holiday, and I plug it into Hotel TV, but I cant control it, necessitating me to bring along my remote.

I am hoping I can set it up so that it can, in that case, host its own wifi, so that I can connect to it and either operate it from there, or configure the hotel wifi and switch to that. I have limitless remote for controlling the stick once wifi is connected.

Tl;Dr Is there an app/way (can be root only) which I can autorun on my tv stick which checks if there is a known hotspot, and if not it hosts its own Wifi hotspot so I can connect directly to it.

I cant have it just permanently do this because I also use it regularly at home, where I do not want this behaviour.

Comment: possibly similar to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27136/trigger-wifi-hotspot-based-on-known-wifi-availability-or-location although is there a free app which is possibly simple to use/single purpose?

Comment: Similar to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/125592/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-turn-off-the-wireless-hotspot-once-i-get-back-ho?rq=1 too, but I doubt my android TV stick has a GPS chip. Also I dont need it to turn off android hotspot automatically, I would end up restarting it when I get home anyway.